# Element Not Interactable even after moving to the element and explicitly waiting in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I click into the vendor box it pops up with a list of options that you can scroll to or type what you want and select. The box has a clear id and is definitely interactable on the actual page but when I run the test it just says element is not interactable.

I've read other threads and have tried to use Actions to move to the element and to explicitly wait which when I have done, has thrown an error "waiting for visibility of the element". 
//Attempt to move to the element

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id(TransactionUIConstants.VENDOR_SEARCH)));

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Page.TIMEOUT);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("vendor")))); 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("vendor"))));
    //What I'm trying to click

    driver.findElement(By.id("vendor")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("vendor")).sendKeys("Amazon");
    driver.findElement(By.id("vendor")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Here's the description from the inspect tab:

input name="" id="vendor" type="text" autocomplete="nope" placeholder="Select option" tabindex="0" class="multiselect__input" style="width: 0px; position: absolute; padding: 0px;"

Comment: which of those last 3 lines is giving you the error about not being interactable? Also which browser? I think I once solved this kind of problem by sending the keys to the window or document. But do you need to send the keys, or is it equally good if you find the right text and click the right option?

Comment: Because assuming the first click works, after you could click on the element found by xpath  //option[contains(text(), "Amazon")]

Comment: It's the first line throwing the error, which I've tried just sending keys without clicking and it also throws the same error.

Comment: So maybe the vendor really isn't interactable and the manual click does something to something inside it. I'm wondering (though some browsers don't like when you click on something you cannot see) if the approach at https://javabeginnerstutorial.com/selenium/9u-webdriver-select-items-two-ways/ method 1 first block of code would work for you.

Comment: I got some help and apparently it's part of a different library so we ended up having to do this:

Comment: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("modal-open")));

WebElement vendor = driver.findElement(By.id("vendor"));
WebElement venParentDiv = vendor.findElement(By.xpath("./../.."));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(venParentDiv));
venParentDiv.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
venParentDiv.sendKeys(transReq.getVendor());
vendor.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("center-block")),
ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("row"))));

Comment: what a pain. glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

If it has select tag you can try using select class. I am assuming that it might be a multiselect dropdown

Comment: I've tried this as well but when I run it, the error says, "element should have been "select" but was "input".

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: 1
2
3
4
5
6
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.port=465
mail.transport.protocol=smtp

Comment: private Folder folder;

  public enum EmailFolder {
    INBOX("INBOX"),
    SPAM("SPAM");

    private String text;

    private EmailFolder(String text){
      this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
      return text;
    }
  }

Comment: /**
   * Uses email.username and email.password properties from the properties file. Reads from Inbox folder of the email application
   * @throws MessagingException
   */
  public EmailUtils() throws MessagingException {
    this(EmailFolder.INBOX);
  }

Comment: are you sure you mean to be answering this question?  Yours seems to be bout email, and this is about picking something off a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.port=465
mail.transport.protocol=smtp


resource folder-1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
utility class- 2

 private Folder folder;

  public enum EmailFolder {
    INBOX("INBOX"),
    SPAM("SPAM");

    private String text;

    private EmailFolder(String text){
      this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
      return text;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It seems that you have posted many answers to the same question. Did you mean to provide seperate answers or are they part of one big answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
   * Uses email.username and email.password properties from the properties file. Reads from Inbox folder of the email application
   * @throws MessagingException
   */
  public EmailUtils() throws MessagingException {
    this(EmailFolder.INBOX);
  }

  /**
   * Uses username and password in properties file to read from a given folder of the email application
   * @param emailFolder Folder in email application to interact with
   * @throws MessagingException
   */
  public EmailUtils(EmailFolder emailFolder) throws MessagingException {
    this(getEmailUsernameFromProperties(),
        getEmailPasswordFromProperties(),
        getEmailServerFromProperties(),
        emailFolder);
  }

  /**
   * Connects to email server with credentials provided to read from a given folder of the email application
   * @param username Email username (e.g. janedoe@email.com)
   * @param password Email password
   * @param server Email server (e.g. smtp.email.com)
   * @param emailFolder Folder in email application to interact with
   */
  public EmailUtils(String username, String password, String server, EmailFolder emailFolder) throws MessagingException {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    try {
      props.load(new FileInputStream(new File("resources/email.properties")));
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect(server, username, password);


    folder = store.getFolder(emailFolder.getText());
    folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
  }
```